# .htaccess - changing urls - RewriteRule not working

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, permalinks

I'm fairly new to this, hopefully you can help me fix this problem.

I have a URL structure that gets an id from a database and shows the url like this:

```
www.website.com/post.php?P=18
```

I would like to present the URL's as:

```
www.website.com/post/18
```

In my .htaccess file, I've altered it like so:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^post/(\w+)$ post.php?P=$1
```

I've read through a few posts about this here on SO but I can't seem to figure it out.

I followed this:

```
The Rule:
RewriteRule ^user/(\w+)/?$ user.php?id=$1

Pattern to Match:
^              Beginning of Input
user/          The REQUEST_URI starts with the literal string "user/"
(\w+)          Capture any word characters, put in $1
/?             Optional trailing slash "/"
$              End of Input

Substitute with:
user.php?id=   Literal string to use.
$1             The first (capture) noted above.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's important to share this kind of information for others that may be having the same issue so here goes.

**The Problem:**

[1] A link that looked like: `www.example.com/news.php?P=1`

The link should look like `www.example.com/news/1`

Then, the link would have to end up showing text instead of an ID. `www.example.com/news/news-name`

**The solution**

First, i had anchor tags that looked like this

```
<a href="news.php?P='.$row['post_id'].'" class="btn btn-link"></a>
```

It gave the first result in the URL [1]. To change it so it would present as a `www.example.com/news/1`, i had to do the following:

Create a htaccess file and fill it like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC]
### THIS IS AN EXAMPLE FOR MULTIPLE EXPRESSIONS ###
#RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) news.php?P=$1&name=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) news.php?P=$1 [NC,L]
```

And then, change the anchor tags to: `<a href="news/'.$row['post_id'].'" class="btn btn-link"></a>`

[1] Would be done now.

The challenge now was to use a slug instead of an ID. On the post creation page, I added the following PHP:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF8');
function slugit($str, $replace=array(), $delimiter='-') {
    if ( !empty($replace) ) {
        $str = str_replace((array)$replace, ' ', $str);
    }
    $clean = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str);
    $clean = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\/_|+ -]/", '', $clean);
    $clean = strtolower(trim($clean, '-'));
    $clean = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $clean);
    return $clean;
}
?>
```

Then, on the news insertion page, I added: `$slug = slugit("$entry1");`, which would pass   `$entry1 = $_POST['title'];` as the title of the page, but slugified. On the database for the news, i created a column to accommodate `$slug` as a permalink name.

Now to present the URL with the slug, I had to change the anchor tag to:

```
<a href="news/'.$row['permalink'].'" class="btn btn-link"></a>
```

And on the htaccess, change `RewriteRule ^news/([0-9]+) news.php?P=$1 [NC,L]` to `RewriteRule ^news/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+) news.php?P=$1 [NC,L]`

That's how I got it to work. I hope this will help people with similar problems fix theirs.

Answer (score 0):

Try with below,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^post/(\w+)$ post.php?P=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hello @AbhishekGurjar, thank you for your answer, I pasted in your code on the htaccess but it still doesn't work. It still presents posts as https://www.website/post.php?P=18

Best regards